# Running a ros2 package in virtual anaconda environment in ROS2 Humble

Tags: ros2, python, environment, anaconda

I have created a virtual anaconda environment in ROS2 (HUMBLE). In that I have installed tensorflow , torch. I have a ros2 package in which there are nodes that i want to run using ros2 run. When I do this the python interpreter is trying to look for libraries in ROS2 environment. How can I set the path so that it will use anaconda python interpreter and will search for libraries in anaconda environment.

steps I am doing:

```
conda activate Myenv
cd ros2_ws/
source ...
ros2 run Mypackage mynode.
```

error i am getting:

```
No module found named torch, no module found named tensorflow.
```

I have installed them in anaconda environment using `pip install tensorflow`.

Verification of this libraries installation is working. i.e in the conda environment after python, and importing these libraries and writing a code then it runs. But when I do cd ros2_ws, source .. and execute my node then it tries to look for the libraries in the ros2 environment instead of anaconda environment.

I have written 'source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash' in the .bashrc file. is this the issue?

Also after anaconda installation,

> > > conda initialize >>>
> > > !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
> > > __conda_setup="$('/home/server/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
> > > if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
> > > eval __conda_setup"
> > > else
> > > if [ -f "/home/server/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
> > > . "/home/server/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
> > > else
> > > export PATH="/home/server/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
> > > fi
> > > fi
> > > unset __conda_setup
> > > <<< conda initialize <<<

this was added to the .bashrc file.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Saurabh Yeola. What do you see when you try `conda list` after sourcing your ros2 workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Your error suggests that the packages are not installed in your conda environment.
So, my guess is the pip you used to installed the packages did not belong to the conda environment.
You can check it by running the command
`which pip` if the output is like

```
(control) user@user:~$ which pip
/home/user/miniconda3/envs/control/bin/pip
```

It implies the pip belongs to your currently active active enviornment and will install packages in this env if you use `pip install`.

But if you see something like this

```
(control) user@user:~$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

it implies this pip is not from your conda env.

Its preferred to use `conda install <pkg>` after activating your conda env or if you prefer pip first activate your conda env run `conda install pip` then use `pip install <pkg>`.
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have checked for the pip path as you suggested. This is not the issue it seems. Do you have any other suggestion, Thank you.